# Wordpress: automatically add images from youtube video within the post

Tags: wordpress, function, youtube

I'm adding some youtube videos to some articles, but they don't have an image.

Is there a way for the video image to be automatically added within the post?

I don't want to store the image on my server, I want the youtube image link to be embedded just below the post title.

I saw a plugin that stores the image on the server, but I would like the image from youtube itself.

Example:

Post title

Image

```
<a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/05FTMpoyoK4/sddefault.jpg" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/05FTMpoyoK4/sddefault.jpg" width="400" height="300" data-original-width="640" data-original-height="480" /></a>
```

Is there a function that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following format

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg

<a href="#" imageanchor="1" ><img border="0" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/dsyXyz_kQuk/0.jpg" width="400" height="300" data-original-width="640" data-original-height="480" /></a>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a way to automatically add the external image of the youtube video within posting